# how to use select case statement with sql transaction

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2005

i have one crm application. i found query in my db implementation while staff user post reply of inquiry i have to insert new inquiry ans to one table and modify another table data same time. i applied logic of as well as i represent my stored proc. but error occured in this proc.

```
set ANSI_NULLS ON
set QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[InquiryPostReply]
(
    @Inquiry_id VARCHAR(50),
    @Priority_type VARCHAR(25),
    @Status_name VARCHAR(50),
    @Inquiry_Content VARCHAR(1024),
    @NewId VARCHAR(50) OUT
)
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;
declare @var1 int
declare @var2 int
declare @uniqueRef char(14)
set @uniqueRef = dbo.UniqueRefNum(rand(), rand(), rand(), rand())
set @var1= (SELECT [Id] FROM [OmStocks].[dbo].[tbl_Status_master] WHERE (Status_name=@Status_name))
set @var2= (SELECT [Id] FROM [OmStocks].[dbo].[tbl_Priority_master] WHERE (Priority_name=@Priority_type))
    SELECT 
        CASE @Status_name
        WHEN 'Open' THEN
            BEGIN TRAN;
            BEGIN TRY
                INSERT INTO [OmStocks].[dbo].[tbl_Inquiry_master]
                ([Id],[Inquiry_id],[Priority_id],[Status_id],[Inquiry_Content],[TimeStamp])
                VALUES
                (@uniqueRef,@Inquiry_id,@var2,@var1,@Inquiry_Content,CONVERT(DATETIME,GETDATE(), 101))
                UPDATE [OmStocks].[dbo].[tbl_Inquiry_History] 
                    SET [Priority_id] = @var2,[Status_id] = @var1,[IsDisplay] = 1,[IsReplied] = 1,[TimeStamp] = CONVERT(DATETIME,GETDATE(), 101)
                WHERE (Inquiry_id=@Inquiry_id)
            COMMIT TRAN;
            END TRY;
        WHEN 'Close' THEN
            BEGIN TRAN;
            BEGIN TRY
                INSERT INTO [OmStocks].[dbo].[tbl_Inquiry_master]
                ([Id],[Inquiry_id],[Priority_id],[Status_id],[Inquiry_Content],[TimeStamp])
                VALUES
                (@uniqueRef,@Inquiry_id,@var2,@var1,@Inquiry_Content,CONVERT(DATETIME,GETDATE(), 101))
                UPDATE [OmStocks].[dbo].[tbl_Inquiry_History] 
                    SET [Priority_id] = @var2,[Status_id] = @var1,[IsDisplay] = 0,[IsReplied] = 1,[TimeStamp] = CONVERT(DATETIME,GETDATE(), 101),[Activity_expire_time] = CONVERT(DATETIME,GETDATE(), 101)
                WHERE (Inquiry_id=@Inquiry_id)
            COMMIT TRAN;
            END TRY; 
    END
    SET @NewId = @uniqueRef
END
```

error occured like:

```
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure InquiryPostReply, Line 21
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'BEGIN'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure InquiryPostReply, Line 31
Incorrect syntax near ';'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure InquiryPostReply, Line 43
Incorrect syntax near ';'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure InquiryPostReply, Line 46
Incorrect syntax near 'END'.
```

please help me...

Comment: It looks like you are trying to use a `SELECT CASE` from VB in your SQL.  Those keywords exist, but they don't do the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `CASE` for this. `CASE` is an expression that returns a single result, not a statement that can be used for control-of-flow. I do understand that `CASE` is used that way in some other languages, but it's just not possible in T-SQL.

```
IF @Status_name = 'Open' THEN
BEGIN
  -- do stuff
END

IF @Status_name = 'Close' THEN
BEGIN
  -- do other stuff
END
```